# Using Ansible for ScaleIO provisioning

Tags: ansible, emc

I am using this playbook to install a 3 node ScaleIO cluster on CentOS 7.

https://github.com/sperreault/ansible-scaleio

In the EMC documentation they specify that a CSV file needs to be uploaded to the IM to complete installation, I am not sure though how I can automate that part within this playbook. Has anyone got any practical experience of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

this playbook is used to install ScaleIO manually, not by IM.
so you do not need to prepare a csv file

Comment: you can define the parameters in the hosts file instead of csv file used by IM